# Draw parts of a split rectangle in a dashed/dotted style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I try to draw parts of a split rectangle in a dashed or dotted style. Thus I want the following code

```
\node[draw,rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split horizontal]
  {foo \nodepart[text width=2cm]{second} bar};
```

to produce an image like this:

[image]

The dashed/dotted part should look uniform, i.e., the different lengths of the dashes in the picture are a result of my bad paint skills ;-)

I also would like to use the same effect for a vertical split rectangle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Draw the whole border after the node is built:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split horizontal,
    align=center,
    alias=othername, 
    append after command={\pgfextra
        \draw ($(othername.one split south)!.25!(othername.south east)$)-|(othername.west)|-($(othername.one split north)!.25!(othername.north east)$);
        \draw ($(othername.one split south)!.75!(othername.south east)$)-|(othername.east)|-($(othername.one split north)!.75!(othername.north east)$);
        \draw[dashed] ($(othername.one split south)!.25!(othername.south east)$)--($(othername.one split south)!.75!(othername.south east)$);
        \draw[dashed] ($(othername.one split north)!.25!(othername.north east)$)--($(othername.one split north)!.75!(othername.north east)$);
        \draw (othername.one split north)--(othername.one split south);
    \endpgfextra} ]
  {foo \nodepart[text width=2cm, draw=none]{second} bar};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like how clean this solution is and also how extensible. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4):

Try overdraw the second part of multi part node with white dashed line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  mpnh/.style = {% multi part node horisontal
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split horizontal, 
        draw, outer sep=0pt, align=center}
                        ]
\node (mpnh) [mpnh]
    {foo 
    \nodepart[text width=2cm]{second} bar};
\draw[white, semithick, dashed] (mpnh.two north)+(-0.5,0) -- ++ (.5,0)
                                (mpnh.two south)+(-0.5,0) -- ++ (.5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]